# Passing `self` reference while iterating through a member

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I know in Rust, there can't be multiple reference to one object if one of them is mutable. So when I want to pass `self` as a reference inside a  loop that is borrowing a member already, it wouldn't compile.

I have a trait function that takes a reference to `bar`:

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn perform(&mut self, bar: &Bar);
}
```

In `Bar`, I have a vector of `Foo`s:

```rust
struct Bar {
    foos: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>,
}
```

The following code would not compile because it's borrowing `self` twice

```rust
impl Bar {
    fn do_it(&mut self) {
        for foo in &mut self.foos {
            foo.perform(self);
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:12:25
   |
11 |         for foo in &mut self.foos {
   |                    --------------
   |                    |
   |                    mutable borrow occurs here
   |                    mutable borrow later used here
12 |             foo.perform(self);
   |                         ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

Is there nice way to do it so `Foo::perform()` can use the references of both `self` and `bar` without the compiler complaining?

### Edit

A couple ways i thought of to get around this:

1. Use pointer

```rust
fn do_it(&mut self) {
    let ptr = self as *const Bar;
    for foo in &mut self.foos {
        foo.perform(ptr);
    }
}
```

2. Take away from the vector then put it back after

```rust
fn do_it(&mut self) {
    let len = self.foos.len();
    for i in 0..len {
         let foo = self.foos.swap_remove(i);
         foo.perform(self);
         self.foos.push(foo);
         self.foos.swap(i, len-1);
    }
}
```

Both ways are not rusty, though. I'm still looking for a way to make `perform()` get the fields from Bar without taking its reference.

Comment: No. Your `perform` method is allowed to empty out the `foos` vector, leading to memory unsafety. The compiler cannot allow this. Make finer-grained functions or types to be explicit that `perform` cannot possibly alter `foos`.

Comment: Shouldn't it not be allowed to do that since it takes bar as immutable reference?

Comment: Sorry, I got it mixed up. It's disallowed because given `&Bar`, you could get a second reference to `self`. For example, `self.foos[0].perform(self)` / `fn perform(&mut self, bar: &Bar) { bar.foos[0] }`. This would allow a mutable and immutable reference to alias.